# Get nearest Latitude and Longitude from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a performance orientated array lookup that will return the closest longitude and latitude relative to the users current location.

One issue is that I have 5000 locations in my array and am needing to loop through all results returning the closest in as fast a time as possible, I am also having issues with the filter as currently it is returning the wrong results (which I believe is due to the lookup only looking for the closest negative to current)

Here is my code:

```
    if(has('geolocation')){

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

                // Example result from getCurrentPosition (this is my exact location)
                //
                // position.coords = {
                //  latitude: 51.4523,
                //  longitude: -0.9724
                // }

                // This is the nearest location
                //
                // location = {
                //  latitude: 51.457495699999996,
                //  longitude: -0.973083
                // }

                // This is the location my filter keeps returning
                //
                // location = {
                //  latitude: "50.6931",
                //  longitude: "-4.0094",
                //  name: "Yes Tor"
                // }

                let closest = this.locations.filter((location) => {
                    console.log(location, position.coords);
                    return location.latitude <= position.coords.latitude && location.longitude <= position.coords.longitude;
                }).pop();


                console.log(closest); //Is incorrect

            });

        }
```

I have commented my current results, my question is if there is a faster way of doing this and if there is a way to get closest for both negative and positive from current.

If anyone needs it here is an example of the array structure (length is 5968)

```
            let this.locations = [
                {
                    elevation: "936.0",
                    id: "350001",
                    latitude: "56.8716",
                    longitude: "-4.1969",
                    name: "A' Bhuidheanach Bheag",
                    region: "ta",
                    unitaryAuthArea: "Perth and Kinross"
                },
                {
                    elevation: "999.0",
                    id: "350024",
                    latitude: "57.6926",
                    longitude: "-5.1328",
                    name: "A'Chailleach (Fannaich Region)",
                    region: "he",
                    unitaryAuthArea: "Highland"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Is your array sorted in any way?

Comment: Yeah I have sorted it in alphabetical order by the name key, the reason for this is the values are appended to a select where the user can change the location as oppose to using the html5 geolocation api.

Comment: hmm now that I see your example array, would it be a safe assumption that it's all pretty small-scale? that means altitude becomes more relevant than the curvature of the Earth for calculating distances…

Comment: Yes each object only contains a few chunks of data, I am just writing some logic from your suggestion below. If it helps it is all UK based and so locations are very close together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find distance between 2 points (Haversine formula):

```
function distance(position1,position2){
    var lat1=position1.latitude;
    var lat2=position2.latitude;
    var lon1=position1.longitude;
    var lon2=position2.longitude;
    var R = 6371000; // metres
    var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
    var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
    var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
    var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

    var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

    var d = R * c;
    return d;
}
```

Now use:

```
var closest=locations[0];
var closest_distance=distance(closest,position.coords);
for(var i=1;i<locations.length;i++){
    if(distance(locations[i],position.coords)<closest_distance){
         closest_distance=distance(locations[i],position.coords);
         closest=locations[i];
    }
}
```

This has complexity of O(n). For 5000 locations that will be good enough most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

You should build a kdtree (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) from all the locations and use that to lookup the closest point from the user location.

Implementations-
See [Solid k-d tree implementation in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612329/solid-k-d-tree-implementation-in-javascript) for some implementations available.

Comment: +1 especially if it's on small distances not too close to the poles you can ignore curvature and just use raw lat/lon/altitude. If the cluster crosses the zero meridian you can rotate all values by 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

All right, if it's all in the UK you'll definitely want to rotate the locations to avoid crossing the zero meridian (add 180 degrees to all longitudes, mod 360). Also scale lat/lon so that one degree in either direction is roughly the same distance at the UK's latitude.

Then you can follow sray's advice assuming a cartesian 3D space.

Or, if your locations array keep changing and you don't want to rebuild a tree every time, just map every location to its 3D cartesian distance and find the minimum. Shouldn't be too slow with just 5k locations.